# jQuery Get Value From Looping in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery. Now I want to get value base on ID value from textbox loop.

Example :

```
<?php
while
{
$id = $d['id'];
?>
<input type="text" name="text" id="txt" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn_confirms" id="txt<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Go"/>
<?php
}
```

and jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
$(".btn_confirms").click(function()
{
var txt_id = $('#txt').val();
alert(txt_id);
}
});
```

Example if I have 3 data.
The problem is, when I click button Go, it just show first value of PHP loop. Another button Go 2 & 3 is show same value.

Any help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have duplicate IDs on the page, they should be unique. For repeating elements either use classes, or make IDs unique (like you're doing for the buttons).

Something like this should work:

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="txt<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn_confirms" id="button<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Go"/>
```

Then, to fetch the id of the input field from the click function, you can do something like this:

```
$(".btn_confirms").click(function()
{
    var txt_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('button', 'txt');
    var value = $('#'+txt_id).val();
    alert(txt_id + ": " + value);
})
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/R9s2R/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<?php
while
{
    $id = $d['id'];
?>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="txt<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn_confirms" id="btn<?php echo $id; ?>" textbox_id="#txt<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Go"/>
<?php
}
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".btn_confirms").click(function()
    {
        var textbox_id = $(this).attr('textbox_id');
        var textbox_val = $(textbox_id).val();
        alert(textbox_val);
    });
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6H5Y/)**